# Win 2012 AD, can't login with some users: there are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with a fresh AD created, I have the admin user and test1. I added to the domain another Windows Server 2012 R2 machine and I can't log with the admin user, I get that error all the time, but I can login with test1.  Tried to create another user and I'm getting the same error.

Any idea on what is causing the error? I hope I explained myself good enough.

Comment: Are you attempting to authenticate the admin user locally or to the new domain?

Comment: Check to see if the member server is in the AD DNS

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct DNS informaton configured on the network adapter on those computers?  The primary DNS server should likely be your Active Directory server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to login to the administrator account, and not just "admin". If it's administrator, if you have a domain user account that matches your domain user account, the computer will always try to login to the machine first. Try putting in `[domain]\administrator` as your user name.

Comment: Yeah thats what im doing already, it seems I can only login with test1 user, it seems im not connected to the domain or something, if I try with a random username and password I get the same as if I couldnt onnect to the AD, but I can ping from one computer to the other.

Comment: Open Windows Explorer and in the address bar type \\servername then hit enter and see if the NETLOGON and SYSVOL shares are present.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify just in case, are you using "admin" or "Administrator" as the username?  I know this may not apply exactly to you using STANDARD, but after I install my "Essentials version" it "deactivates" the "Administrator" local account after set up.  And I think "Administrator" is reserved and cannot be used... so you have to use another name like just "admin".  Just a thought that may or may not help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the computer where you are logging in actually joined to the domain. Also check it's DNS settings; it should be using the domain controller as it's DNS server.